# How to convert RGB24 to RGB for web?

Tags: javascript, colors, rgb, 24-bit

I have some colors in RGB24 format, for example: `1581613`
How to convert it to RGB for web usage?
If I understand correctly, the format is as follows `RRRGGBB`.

Last code i've trying to run is:

```
const color = 1581613;

const red   = (color >> 5) * 255 / 7;
const green = ((color >> 2) & 0x07) * 255 / 7;
const blue  = (color & 0x03) * 255 / 3;
```

But my attempts did not lead to success.

Comment: hello, what is `1581613`? what does it stand for?

Comment: `const hexcol = "#" + color.toString(16).padStart(6, '0');`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG! Great answer in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing a lot here, but here goes:

```js
const color = 1581613;

const red   = (color >> 16) & 255;
const green = (color >> 8) & 255;
const blue  = color & 255;

const hex = red.toString(16) + green.toString(16) + blue.toString(16);

document.write(JSON.stringify({rgb: [red, green, blue], hex }, null, 2));
```